# How to dynamically resize table views inside a scroll view

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, resize, contentsize

I want to display two table views inside a uiscrollview and make the table views resize dynamically to fit their content. The table views should not be scrollable, hence the embedding in a scroll view. I have managed to resize the scroll view appropriately. The setup is as follows:

---

UILabel1

TableView1

..some extra space..

UILabel2

TableView2

---

I suspect that this should be possible with auto layout, but I need help to get started (I'm new to auto layout). Furthermore, I know that the labels could be added to the headers of the table views, but for now this will do. The data is fetched asynch over a network connection, so the table views need to be updated when the data is in.
Optionally, a couple of spinner could occupy the table view space until the data is ready to be displayed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use a grouped UITableView with multiple sections and return UILabel objects as the UIView for each section?

Comment: Good point, I might just go that way. The reason I didn't was because of the look of it. I wanted them completely separated and wanted a quick and dirty solution without too much customization.